# Windows 10 Minimum Required VRAM

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, vram

VirtualBox has 128MB set for default VRAM amount. I was wondering if I could get VBox to use less memory and free memory on the host (or host VRAM) if I decrease the VMRAM amount if I'm not using graphics intensive applications.

Same applies for any other virtualization software or physical video cards.

Comment: You could simply experiment and find out what works for you.

Comment: A typical guest needs 2 GB of memory. 16 GB allows me to run host plus 3 guests.

Comment: @John, I know the amount of RAM, but what about Video RAM?

Comment: @gronostaj I was considering that but didn't want to risk going below the minimum required.

Comment: There is no video RAM setting in VMware (never has been so far as I recall), just main memory. VMware has a video adapter of its own (so machines can be simply ported to another machine). I do not know if VB has video memory but I do not think so.

Comment: @John It does. You can adjust video memory 1-128 MB.

Comment: It's a VM, you don't risk anything. Make a snapshot before hand. If anything goes wrong, just restore the snapshot.

Comment: I do not see such a setting in VMware Workstation 15, even in the extra settings for display.

Comment: I was talking about VirtualBox and any others that may have had the setting. I wasn't aware if it was on VMWare or not, I mostly use VirtualBox. So this question does not apply to VMWare then. The question was not specific to VirtualBox (just using that as my example) or even to virtualization. There could be users wondering if their physical video card with XYZ about of VRAM will work on Windows 10.

Comment: 16MB should be enough for basic functions.  I've run WinServer2019 with a full GUI on a 16MB video card.

Comment: VMware Workstation does allow you to adjust it's VRAM, up to 2GB. VM Settings\Hardware\display\ p.147 of the Workstation v15 manual.